# Only displaying connecting to server, not loading JSON data

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to get some JSON data using `HttpURLConnection`, but I only get Connecting server displaying and nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class JSONParsingFragment extends Fragment{
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
    ActorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View vw=inflater.inflate(R.layout.jsonparse_fragment, container, false);
        lv=(ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");
        adapter = new ActorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.jsonparsedata_item, actorsList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return  vw;
    }

    class JSONAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        String result;
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(url));
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Actors actor = new Actors();

                        actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                        actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                        actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
                        actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                        actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                        actor.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                        actor.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                        actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                        actorsList.add(actor);

                        Log.v("log", "response");
                    }


                } } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;}

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

}
```

In the console log I have:

`org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

So it seems I have an error in this part:

```
 if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                        JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(url));
                        JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Show your JSON data

Comment: I see now an error in console: BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/brad.jpg (No such file or directory), probably because the image is URL in JSON, but I tried also to decode it with no luck. So I can't get the images displayed. The JSOn data is just for testing and is here http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors

Comment: The Asynctask isn't responsible for displaying the image. The ActorAdapter is, which is missing from the question. You need another, separate thread to download the images

Comment: I know but in the ActorAdapter.java I have that - Picasso.with(context).load(actorList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageview); It worked before when I had http Entity connection. After I switched to httpsurlconnection, the image stopped displaying. So the issue must be in my provided code, I also updated my question with ActorAdapter.java code

Comment: You aren't using any https site... Have you tried using Volley library? Asynctask is just a bunch of unnecessary code to maintain

Comment: No, I wanted to avoid using more libraries, the whole list is working fine, just the images not :(

Comment: Again, the Images are not images. They are URLs, which you need to get again. Picasso works without any HttpEntity or HttpURLConnection object, so I don't know what you're trying to say

Comment: By the way, no part of the code you've shown is loading the ActorAdapter into a ListView

Comment: Ok, finally I did it! I updated my code in my question. Now everything is working fine, including images!

Comment: Please don't "fix" any questions you have asked. Since this particular one is a duplicate, either delete it, leave it as it was, or, if you really feel you must, edit it and **append** your solution to the bottom. Another thing, don't edit your question so it asks something else. Post a new question. That's what you should have done for your "images" issue.